# Не понятный для меня вывод div в консоль

Tags: javascript

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
div.innerHTML = 'raz';
console.log(div);
div.innerHTML = 'dva';
console.log(div);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Почему в консоли два раза выводится 'dva'. А не 'raz' и следом 'dva'.

---

[image: console]
Проверил в трех браузерах. Везде такой вывод.

Comment: Все правильно выводиться. Сначала `raz`, потом `dva`

Comment: Я проверил в 3х браузерах. Два раза выводиться 'dva'.

Comment: у сниппета кнопку Выполнить нажмите, тоже dva-dva чтоль ?

Comment: Подтверждаю что два-два в хроме. Снипет тут не при чём.

Comment: @teran если заглянуть именно в консоль браузера, а не консоль сниппета — то да, будет dva-dva

Comment: `console.dir` тогда в помощь, или что там?

Comment: и там тоже dva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30150527/11929476) на английском на схожий вопрос.

Не факт, что синхронность консоли гарантирована в этом случае. Скорее всего на момент когда консоль выводит на экран первый раз, `div` уже имеет второй текст. Если вы именно `div.innerHTML` напишите, то будет верно, потому что выводится текст, а не представление дива. Такое же поведение может быть во многих местах консоли, когда вы выводите объекты вместо примитивов.

Answer (score 2):

> Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что если вы логируете объекты в
> последних версиях Chrome и Firefox, **то что вы вывели в консоль,
> является ссылкой на объект, и не обязательно является его "значением"
> на момент вызова** console.log()

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: иначе говоря, сериализуйте представление объекта перед выводом, если хотите увидеть состояние на момент вызова